# IOS Segue not appearing. No error

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to implement a segue programmatically in IOS.

My story board looks like this:

[image]

The first segue between the first two screens is done by connecting the Login button to the next screen (so not completely programmatically), and it works fine.

The issue is with the "secondSegue", which I tried doing programmatically.
It simply does not work and there is no error message appearing.

I connected the 'Load this Screen' button to the following action in the Second Screen's view controller:

`@IBAction func openThirdScreen(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondSegue", sender: nil)
    }`

But the screen isn't opening and there is no error.

All the proper IBOutlets seem connected so I don't know what the issue could be.

I put a print statement in openThirdScreen(), and it prints, but a print statement in the third screen's View Controller's viewDidLoad() does not print, even though
I made sure the third screen was connected to a view controller.

I had overridden `performSegue()` earlier in order to do more with the segue but it was not working so I removed it for simplicity.

Please let me know what I messed up.
Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm very new to XCode and I couldn't find anyone online with the same issue.

Let me know if there are more screenshots that are necessary to answer my question.

Edit: the following image was requested, in order to answer the question
[image: Image of expanded storyboard structure]

Comment: reconnect your segue in storyboard and see if it helps at all. Are you using the latest Xcode?

Comment: Yes, I am. And yeah, thanks for the suggestion but I already tried reconnecting it. I have deleted the segue, gone to the left tab and control dragged between the two UIViews once again. Unfortunately, it did not help.

Comment: Are you dragging between the UIViews or the ViewControllers?

Comment: The view controllers. Should I be dragging between the views?

Comment: Can you please post your storyboard document outline (left hand column) with all your viewcontrollers expanded.

Comment: I added the picture to the question. Please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146097/discussion-between-siriss-and-james-dorfman).